# Символ "<<" в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется фрагмент кода

```
class PolygonPainter(BaseToolClass):

    def __init__(self, canvas, annotationMgr, start):
        super().__init__(canvas, annotationMgr)

        self.start = start
        self.polygon = QPolygonF() << self.start
        self.polygonItem = self.canvas.addPolygon(self.polygon, self.linePen, self.areaBrush)
        print('======== Polygon Annotation Drawing ========')

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.polygon << event.scenePos()
        self.polygonItem.setPolygon(self.polygon)
        self.polygonItem.update()
```

в строках

```
self.polygon = QPolygonF() << self.start

self.polygon << event.scenePos()
```

что означает символ "<<"?

Comment: `x << y` - *Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as multiplying x by 2**y.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

битовый сдвиг `x << y`, сдвинуть битовое представление `x` на `y` разрядов влево и заполнить справа нулями

Например:

```
a = 5 # 101
a = 5 << 2
print(a) # 20 or 10100
```

Answer (score 4):

Как уже написали выше - по умолчанию это побитовый сдвиг.

Но нужно смотреть, не переопределён ли у класса `QPolygonF` специальный метод `__lshift__` - авторы библиотеки вполне могли решить, что `<<` - слишком красивый оператор, чтобы оставлять его для такой редкоиспользуемой операции, как битовый сдвиг, и, возможно, в данном случае он делает что-то совсем другое.

Comment: Поправил код в теме. Добавил объявление класса

Comment: Согласен, в c++/Qt оператор `<<` часто используется для подобных вещей тот же `qDebug << "message";` Поэтому в биндинге на питоне это тоже поддержано. Кст, в документации к QPolygonF явно указано про переопределенный оператор `<<`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpolygonf.html#operator-lt-lt-16

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае оператор `<<` перегружен и используется как в Си++ со значением "записать точку в полигон". Это сделанно для общей семантики Qt.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpolygonf.html#details

Comment: Вот оно чё... Не знал про такое. Благодарю за ответ!